# how to pass an arraylist to other component in react js

Tags: reactjs

My project is a news dashboard with react.js

I have an **advanced news search page** when user clicks on a row in the search result to see the details page but when back to Search page **filter has been reseted**.

Comment: i think the component gets unmounted, so when it mounts back it will have the default state so which means it gets reset

Answer (score 0):

You may try below :

```
<ChildComponent arrayList={this.state.arrayList}>  </ChildComponent>
```

And In receiving component :

```
parentArrayList = this.props.arrayList;
```

Or in contructor, You can use below :

```
class ChildComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          childArrayList = props.arrayList;
        };
    }
}
```

In the above component, You can use **this.state.childArrayList**

Comment: @RezaGhahari, Please have a look.